# Hive metastore not starting

Tags: hadoop, hive

While starting Hive metastore through command
 "hive --service metastore"

getting below error :

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create
>   ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.         at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:93)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Exception in
>   thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could
>   not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.         at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:93)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Killed

Comment: You can check whether the port is free or not using `netstat -nlp | grep 9083`

Comment: Hi Geetika!  nothing is being shown :   [root@CDCUEXDB01 ~]# netstat -nlp | grep 9083
[root@CDCUEXDB01 ~]#